# objective-c: return value

Tags: objective-c, return-value

I'm reading Stephen Kochan's "Programming in Objective-C" (I'm n0000b). Everything has been obvious to me until exercise 4-8.

It asks me to modify methods, in an "Accumulator" class created earlier in the chapter, to "return" the value of the accumulator when one of the math methods is used (basically it's a calculator). I took this originally to mean that I want the program to display the result whenever one of the methods is used (+, -, *, /), so I set it up to do so, so each line displays the cumulative result rather than just the final result:

```
[deskCalc setAccumulator: 0.0];
[deskCalc add: 200.]; //the result is displayed
[deskCalc divide: 100.0]; //the result is displayed
[deskCalc subtract: 1.0]; //the result is displayed
[deskCalc multiply: 5]; //the result is displayed
NSLog (@"The result is %g", [deskCalc accumulator]);
```

But after looking up other people's solutions, it appears that "returning the value of the Accumulator" means something different.

Can someone describe to me what returning a value means, and what purpose it serves? I have looked through the previous chapter a few times but it is still unclear to me how this will make the program behave differently.

Thanks!
-Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation methods you have in your accumulator class probably look something like this at the moment:

```
- (void)add:(float)aFloat {
    result += aFloat;
    NSLog(@"%f", result);
}
```

This method, in its current state, returns nothing (void). It outputs the current total on screen only. That's nice for an exercise, but in real-world programs, a calculation result will probably not be very useful if it's displayed on screen. Instead, you probably will want to do something else with the result, so you want the method to return it. For example, the `NSString` class has a method `length`. This method would not be very useful if it were to print the length of the string on screen. Instead, it *returns* the length, so the program can do something useful with this value (like checking that the string has the correct length):

```
int length = [tweet length];
if (length > 140) {
    // display a useful error message
    ...
} else {
    // tweet it :)
    ...
}
```

To modify your calculator methods to return something, you will (a) have to change the method signature to have a return value, and (b) to actually return this value.

In the method signature, simply change the return type to something other than void. In your example, the correct type would probably be float (or whatever type the calculator is using internally for its current result).

```
- (float)add:(float)aFloat {
    ...
}
```

To actually return the current value, you would add a `return` statement add the end of your method (before the closing `}`)

```
return result;
```

(this assumes that `result` is the instance variable containing the current calculation result).

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I'm still confused, however, about how then my "accumulator" value can 'remember' what it's previous value was in my program, even if I dont add "return accumulator" to each of the math methods. For instance, it starts at 0, then I "add 200", then I "subtract 5", then if I print the result it tells me "195". How does it keep track if I'm not returning the value to "accumulator" each time?

Comment: In my example, I assumed that result was an instance variable `float result;` declared in the calculator's class interface. This instance variable stays around during the entire lifetime of your calculator instance, so every time you perform an operation with it, it changes based on its previous value and – with the suggested modifications – its current value after the operation is also returned by the method.

Comment: This example is of course fairly contrived. In a normal program, you would more likely have methods affecting the internal state of your object (e.g. add adding x to the internal result) that don't return anything (or possibly do return an error code to indicate success/failure of the operation), and then another method to get the current state (the current result) of the calculator. Or methods that don't affect the internal state of an object at all but do something with their parameters and then return some kind of result.

Comment: Examples for my last comment: `[name appendString:@" , Ph.D."]` affects the mutable's string object's internal state (if `name` was "John Doe" before, it will afterwards be "John Doe, Ph.D.") but doesn't return anything. On the other hand, `[name stringByAppendingString:@" , Ph.D."]` does not change the `name` string object (it'll still be "John Doe") but returns a new string object containing "John Doe, Ph.D.".

Answer (score 1):

They are asking you to modify your add, divide, substract methods to return the value of the accumulator upon completion of the performed operation.  My guess is that your original add/divide/etc methods defined a (void) return value, meaning they don't return any value from the function call.  As a result you could not perform a execution similar to the following:

```
NSLog(@"Updated value: %g", [deskCalc substract: 1.0]);
```

Returning a value from a function means that not only could the function perform some type of operation, but it also returns some sort of value to the calling code.  The purpose of returning a value is that it allows you to separate your code into logical components, allows for code reuse and increases maintainability of your code.

Here's an example of how it would be useful: let's say you need to calculate the square root of a number.  Your code don't care how the square root is calculated, you just want the number.  By using a function which takes in a value, calculates its square root and then returns the calculated value to the calling code, your code can worry about what it needs to do with the returned value of the function without having to worry about the logic itself.

Here is an example of a function which returns a NSString:

```
- (NSString *) getAString {
    return @"String being returned";
}
```

Here is how you would use that function:

```
NSString *myString = [someObject getAString];
```

I hope this helps you along in your learning process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do get the basic concept, but am still confused by the functionality (unfortunately your example uses syntax that hasn't yet been covered in the book...).

For instance, originally (without "return accumulator;" added to each method, "accumulator" still stores the reply each time an operation was performed on it. "add 20" adds 20 to the original value, then on the next line "subtract 5" will subtract 5 from the accumulated total.